# Any tips for someone who is going to build his first massive app?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have built many different very basic Flutter apps, now I have a big project in my mind but I'm not sure what is the best practice to do this, how i should start, what architecture to use etc. 
Key features of app:

- Will have a section which contains over 200, 3 minutes audio lessons.
- Will have flashcards and flash card quizzes. (over 2000 flashcards, no images, only text)
- Will have about 500 lessons that will unlock after the one before unlocked.

It's just okay if you give me the key words that can help me, I'm happy to search it myself but I'm not sure what i should look for atm.

Comment: The best way to approach this is to just do it. As you're building your app, you'll run into some issues where the first way you're trying to do something might be a bit broken, or might not be very efficient, or it's just plain difficult to manage. That's when you take a step back and reassess what you're trying to do, identify the failings of what you did, and come up with another way that addresses those failings. At that point, you will also have a better idea of what questions to ask when you need help. You will probably end up rewriting the app several times, but that's how it goes.

Comment: General tips in no specific order: Abstract things as often and early as possible, build a library of components you will use and try to maintain a consistent style across the whole project, both in terms of what the user can see and what the developer can see. Identify components that can be modularized - is there login functionality? Is there a database? Home page? And then specify what the interfaces of those modules will look like, I.e. how they will communicate.